# How can I track down a segmentation fault in a Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, segmentation-fault

I'm having a problem with a Cocoa application I am writing. It has to parse a timestamped file that is updated every hour, and during testing it keeps crashing consistently at around 11:45 PM due to a segmentation fault. I'm assuming I must be messaging an object that has been deallocated. What tools are provided with the Xcode install to track object allocations and (hopefully) tell me if I am messaging an object that has been deallocated?

I am using Mac OS X 10.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

- Use [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) to monitor when messages are sent to deallocated NSObjects
- Use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to track object allocations and/or memory leaks

Comment: Do not do these things together. NSZombieEnabled will cause "leaks" to show up in Instruments.

Comment: +1: NSZombie objects are the Apple-prescribed way to deal with something like this. And like nall said, don't use Instruments with zombies enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is by using a command line tool called `gdb`. [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html) is a tutorial on how to use it. You'll have to learn a few of it's commands, but once you do it's almost a pleasure to use.

Note: `gbd` can be used on C, C++, and Objective-C programs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the program under gdb? This should allow you to inspect the stack and variables when it SIGSEGVs.

To track allocations, use [malloc_history](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/malloc_history.1.html). This requires the `MallocStackLogging` environment variable to be set.

Answer (score 0):

A quick point: using a deallocated memory location usually results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception. If that's the crash reason you're seeing then you're correct in assuming it's a deallocation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in Xcode's debugger (which is gdb with a GUI on top) and reproduce the crash. Then, look at the stack trace.

Messaging a deallocated object usually has the top frame in objc_msgSend. The next step then is to run the app with NSZombieEnabled and reproduce the crash; the zombie will identify itself.

Comment: The crash has been a bit difficult to reproduce, but I do know from the crash logs that the fault is occuring in `objc_msgSend`.

Comment: Then the next step is to run it with NSZombieEnabled.